# How to write XPath to get node attribute value from a "Name Space XML" in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, domxpath

INPUT_XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<root xmlns:ns1="http://path1/schema1" xmlns:ns2="http://path2/schema2">
    <ns1:abc>1234</ns1:abc>
    <ns2:def>5678</ns2:def>
</root>
```

In Java, I am trying to write XPath expression which will get the value corresponding to this attribute "xmlns:ns1" from the above INPUT_XML string content.

I've tried the following:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(INPUT_XML);

    String xpathExpression = "/root/xmlns:ns1";

    // Create XPathFactory object
    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

    // Create XPath object
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    // Create XPathExpression object
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpression);

    // Evaluate expression result on XML document
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
```

But the above code is not giving the expected value of the specified attribute i.e. *xmlns:ns1*. I heavily suspect the xPathExpression is wrong. Please suggest with the right XPath expression or the right approach to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an XPath 1.0 processor, or a XPath 2.0 processor with XPath 1.0 compatibility mode turned on, you can use the `namespace` axis to select the namespace value.

You will need to make the following change in your code:

```
String xpathExpression = "/root/namespace::ns1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `xmlns:ns1="http://path1/schema1"` and `xmlns:ns2="http://path2/schema2"` are not attributes, but [namespace declarations](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp). You cannot retrieve them with an XPath declaration so easily (there is XPath function namespace-uri() for this purpose, but root element does not have any namespace, it only defines them for future use).

When using DOM API you could use method lookupNamespaceURI():

```
System.out.println("ns1 = " + doc.getDocumentElement().lookupNamespaceURI("ns1"));
System.out.println("ns2 = " + doc.getDocumentElement().lookupNamespaceURI("ns2"));
```

When using XPath you could try following expressions:

```
namespace-uri(/*[local-name()='root']/*[local-name()='abc'])
namespace-uri(/*[local-name()='root']/*[local-name()='def'])
```